# An Object Reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.Component.transform'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is make it so when my character leave a scene and then re-enters it goes to the position it left in. To do this I thought I could us a variable from one script to save and alter the characters leaving position and then set it to that when it enters the scene.

I want to use the current player position is gets when the player leaves the room.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;



public class HomeBaseLevelSwitchOutside : MonoBehaviour {
    public static Vector3 playerPos =  GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    public GameObject Interaction;

    void Start()
    {
        Interaction.SetActive (false);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D col)
    {


        Interaction.SetActive (true);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E))
            Application.LoadLevel (5);
            HomeBaseLevelSwitchOutside.playerPos =  GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        Interaction.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

And then set my player to that position

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    //floats
    public float maxSpeed = 3;
    public float speed = 50f;
    public float jumpPower = 150f;
    //Bools
    public bool grounded;
    public bool canDoubleJump;
    //Stats
    public int curHealth;
    public int maxHealth = 100;

    //References
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;

    void Start () 
    {

        Player.transform.position = HomeBaseLevelSwitchOutside.playerPos;
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        //transform.position = Player.playerPos;
        curHealth = maxHealth;
    }



    void Update () 
    {
        anim.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);
        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (rb2d.velocity.x));

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < -0.1f) 
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-4, 4, 4);
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0.1f) 
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(4, 4, 4);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) 
        {
            if(grounded)
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);
                canDoubleJump = true;

            }
            else
            {
                if(canDoubleJump)
                {
                    canDoubleJump = false;
                    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (rb2d.velocity.x,0);
                    rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);

                }
            }
        }

        if (curHealth > maxHealth) {
            curHealth = maxHealth;

        }
        if(curHealth <= 0){
            Die ();
        }

    }



    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 easeVelocity = rb2d.velocity;
        easeVelocity.y = rb2d.velocity.y;
        easeVelocity.z = 0.0f;
        easeVelocity.x *= 0.85f;


        float h = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        if(grounded)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = easeVelocity;
        }

        rb2d.AddForce ((Vector2.right * speed) * h);
        if (rb2d.velocity.x > maxSpeed) 
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }
        if (rb2d.velocity.x < -maxSpeed) 
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }

    }
    void Die(){
        //Restart
        Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    }
    public void Damage(int dmg){

        curHealth -= dmg;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("redflash");
    }

    public IEnumerator Knockback(float knockdur, float knockpwr, Vector3 knockdir){
        float timer = 0;
        while (knockdur > timer) {
            timer+=Time.deltaTime;

            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector3(knockdir.x * -100, knockdir.y * knockpwr, transform.position.z));

        }
        yield return 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First line in the Start method of Player:

Change

```
Player.transform.position = HomeBaseLevelSwitchOutside.playerPos;
```

to

```
transform.position = HomeBaseLevelSwitchOutside.playerPos;
```

(You are accessing Transform in a MonoBehaviour, not a static member on the Player class)

Comment: I did this but i get these two errors NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:35)
and NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Player.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:80)

Comment: @ReeceRollings Those aren't related to the error you were getting - the reason they're showing up is because your previous error has been fixed, allowing your code to run and throw these exceptions elsewhere. Try solving them on your own. If after expending great effort you're unable to, then post a new question on Stack Overflow. (TL;DR: Don't add them on to your present question, since they're unrelated.)